# RSS Feeds - add serverside (PHP) or clientside (JavaScript/jQuery)

Tags: php, javascript, rss

A quick Google search of "jquery rss parser" returns many cool plugins.

That being said, what are the pros and cons of adding rss content to my website using server-side versus client-side technology?

Answer (score 0):

Here a few pros and cons:

**PROs**

- Content Dynamically Updated
- Can be flexible to drive the most relevant content to the visitor
- Allows you to style and manipulate the data to keep the site looking consistant

**CONs**

- Client side requires javascript to be enabled on the browser/device.
- Server side while more versatile may require additional installation of modules on the server to work properly
- Server side will not auto update without a page reload
- RSS Feed structure could change requiring a rewrite of your code.
- RSS Feed not outputting properly causing your site not to show the right information (improper tag use or unescaped characters)
- May not be updated right away, I know a few feeds that update on a weekly basis

If you are looking for a way to add content to your site. Look into creating or using a Content Management System. There are available plugins that do the same and will allow you some control over how the data is displayed or interpreted, not to mention can also cache an older feed. A list of most common Content Management Systems can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems

Comment: My request for pros and cons were to help me determine whether I should use server or client side technology to display RSS feeds on my site.  What do you use?

Comment: It depends on what I am trying to accomplish or do. For a site, I use a Content Management System. But for a mobile app, I may use a RSS feed because of security.

Comment: A Content Management System might use either server-side or client-side technology, no?

Comment: No, a Content Management System uses only server side technology (PHP/MySQL or similar) The add-ons or themes may use client-side.

Answer (score 0):

It could be cool to implement it client side, as then you could build really cool user interface, where new RSS items are fetched every few secs / mins (consider Masonry plugin). Client side would allow you to load RSS feeds and display them as soon as content loaded from a source, rather than waiting until all feeds are loaded.

Server side - you would have to consider some sort of caching as parsing feeds may be very time consuming and no one likes waiting....

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a list like the following:

Benefits of using client-side technology for RSS feed:

1. Content can be updated without page reloads
2. Content can be sorted/manipulated without page reloads

Benefits  of server-side technology for RSS feed:

1. Improves SSO
2. Doesn't require the client to have JavaScript enabled.